# Difference between “I thought Ron a mad guy” and “I thought Ron to be mad”?

Tags: difference, infinitives

> I thought Ron to be mad.

Here, Ron is working as an indirect object and 'to be mad' as a direct object.

> I thought Ron a mad guy.

Here, Ron is working as an indirect object and 'a mad guy' as a direct object.

What's the difference then?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, RADS. I'm afraid your analysis is not quite right. In the first example, "Ron" is direct object and the clause "to be mad" is complement of "thought". In the second, "Ron" is direct object and "a mad guy" is objective predicative complement.

Comment: You mean _the infinitive_, not _infinity_!

Comment: Don't spend too much time on this "subjunctive" syntax. Native speakers increasingly tend to avoid it in favour of straightforward *I thought Ron **was** mad.* Discarding the verb completely is syntactically valid *(**I think you silly**)*, but it's dated / literary / stilted. Just stick with "tensed" versions of TO BE - *I think you **are** silly.*

Comment: Both are very clumsy: I thought Ron **was** a crazy guy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning between these sentences:

> *”I thought Ron to be mad.”*

Here, **’Ron’** is the *direct object* and **’to be mad’** is the *objective complement*.

> *”I thought Ron a mad guy”*.

Here, **’Ron’** is the *direct object* and **’a mad guy’** is the *objective complement*.

> *”I thought Ron mad.”*

**’Ron’** >> *direct object*; **’mad’** >> *objective complement*.

> *”I thought (that) Ron was mad.”*

Here, **”(that) Ron was mad”** is the *subordinate noun clause or nominal clause as object of the finite verb* **’thought’**

Answer (score 0):

"Mad" is probably a bad example, as it has multiple meanings. It can mean *angry*, which is usually a temporary state; it can also mean *crazy*, which could be a more permanent state. There are other colloquial meanings, too.

Assuming you mean 'angry' - saying "I thought Ron to be mad" is much the same as saying, "I thought Ron *was* mad". It means that, at the time you are speaking about, you believed that Ron was in an angry state.

Saying that someone is a "mad guy" (or person) is different. You are using the adjective to describe the person, not just their mood. It is an assessment of their overall character.

Answer (score 0):

I think Astralbee had answered your question. But just like BillJ said, your analysis is not quite right.

---

To judge the composition of an object, you can add a linking verb between two object. If you express it smoothly, the second object is the complement, otherwise the indirect object.

In this example, both are smooth.

- Ron is to be mad.
- Ron is a mad guy.

So they are complement objective.

---

PS. I'm not the native English speaker, but a rookie. So what I said may be wrong.

Comment: Ron is to be mad does not work in English.